# Cross-browser still image camera capture

Tags: javascript, html, image-capture

On a web page, I need to be able to capture a still image from the users webcam or phone camera.  It looks like getUserMedia() is only supported by Firefox, Opera and Chrome and I wasn't able to find a still image capture example using it.  Flash won't work on Apple devices.  Is there a single cross-browser solution for this?  If not, what set of solutions will cover desktop and mobile camera capture?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I never found a satisfactory solution.  getUserMedia has better browser support now, but Firefox 41.0.1 crashed constantly when I tried to use it. I pretty much gave up (again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much answer the question yourselves. Only Chrome, Firefox and Opera (desktop from next version) [currently support](http://caniuse.com/stream) `getUserMedia`.

As Flash is unavailable on iOS (as you also mention) you would need to write a native application to support that OS.

So in short: there does not exist a single cross-browser solution for this at the time of this writing.

There are many solutions out there which allow you to grab a video from a web camera running in native environment. You don't mention programming platform so I can't give any specific example but for iOS [this can be a good starting point](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AudioVideoStartingPoint_iOS/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, Ken. You asked about programming platform.  I want to do it all from the web page, hopefully without having to install anything on the user's device.  Is there anything for IOS that would allow that?  So the platform would be HTML5 and Javascript with the possible addition of libraries like jQuery.  Flash would work only because a lot of desktops, laptops and android devices already have it installed.

Comment: @user1981459 not that I know of. As the browser on iOS doesn't support it there is not much we can do but sit and wait until it does. Browser extension may be one approach but then you need the user to install something which you want to avoid.